# How does NSFileHandle offsetInFile work?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfilehandle

I am just wanting to know how offsetInFile works? and what is the difference between seekToFileOffSet. and code examples you know of would be helpfull as well :)

Comment: This question will be closed as it is not a specific code related question, but a discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For standard file descriptors, `-[NSFileHandle offsetInFile]` and `-seekToFileOffset:` have straightforward POSIX equivalents:

```
[handle offsetInFile];
    => off_t offset = lseek([handle fileDescriptor], 0, SEEK_CUR);

[handle seekToFileOffset:off];
    => off_t offset = lseek([handle fileDescriptor], off, SEEK_SET);
```

The difference between them is that the first returns the current offset, while the second changes the offset.

Comment: ah right, and when you say returns offset, is the offset a position in the file? what I am trying to do is open up a file that has say 1000 lines in it and pull a single line from the file based on the number a user enters... am I going down the right track in order to do this?

Comment: The file offset won't be much help to you unless the file has fixed-width lines, like a punchcard. Instead, you'd have to scan the file for newline characters and then save out the characters for the line in question into a buffer.

Comment: interestingly enough each line has a 5 character string.

Comment: If seekToFileOffset allows you to change the offset can you then return the characters that are located in that offset?

Comment: Yes. The file offset is implicitly used when reading bytes from the file; if you issued `read(fd, buf, count)`, the `count` bytes read would be those in the range `(offset, count)`. The `NSFileHandle` equivalent for the POSIX `read` call would be `[handle readDataOfLength:count]`.

Comment: Don't forget to include the newline character in the line length when calculating the offset. To skip `"12345\n"`, you need to skip 6 characters (5 + newline), not 5.

Comment: okay cool, thanks for the information I will have to do more research from this, but you have at least given my more detail to further my investigation. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Just another thing to consider, if you happen to have multibyte characters they may trip you up.